# Lipschitz constant of negative log likelihood function

Tags: convex-optimization, frobenius-method

Show that  $∇l(\mathbf{w})$ is Lipschitz continuous.

I found that $∇l(\mathbf{w})$ is:

[image]

So from the hint, Lipschitz constant is $\frac{1}{2}\frac{y_i}{y_i}||xi||$. I am not sure how to get the Frobenius norm. I think I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $l\colon\mathbb{R}^p \to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $l(w) = \sum_{i=1}^n \log(1+e^{-y_i w^\top x_i})$, we have that
\begin{equation*}
\nabla l(w) = -\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{1+e^{-y_i w^\top x_i}} e^{-y_i w^\top x_i} y_i x_i = -\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{e^{y_i w^\top x_i} + 1} y_i x_i.
\end{equation*}
Denoting the vector $2$-norm by $\|\cdot\|$, we have that
\begin{align*}
\|\nabla l(v) - \nabla l(w)\| ={}& \left\lVert \sum_{i=1}^n \left( \frac{1}{e^{y_i w^\top x_i}+1} y_i x_i - \frac{1}{e^{y_i v^\top x_i} + 1} y_i x_i \right) \right\rVert \\
\le{}& \sum_{i=1}^n \left|\frac{1}{e^{y_i w^\top x_i} + 1} - \frac{1}{e^{y_i v^\top x_i} + 1} \right||y_i|\|x_i\| \\
\le{}& \sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{2}|y_i|\|x_i\| \|v-w\| \right)|y_i| \|x_i\| \\
={}& \left(\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^n |y_i|^2 \|x_i\|^2 \right) \|v-w\|,
\end{align*}
where the first inequality comes from the triangle inequality and the second one comes from the Lipschitz continuity hint you were given. Therefore, $\nabla l$ is Lipschitz continuous with Lipschitz constant
\begin{equation*}
L = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^n |y_i|^2 \|x_i\|^2.
\end{equation*}
In the case that $y_i\in\{-1,1\}$ (which is commonly the case in many machine learning contexts), this reduces to
\begin{equation*}
L = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n \|x_i\|^2 = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^p (x_i)_j^2 = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^p X_{ij}^2 = \frac{1}{2}\|X\|_F^2,
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
X = \begin{bmatrix} x_1^\top \\ x_2^\top \\ \vdots \\ x_n^\top \end{bmatrix},
\end{equation*}
and $\|\cdot\|_F$ denotes the Frobenius norm.